# how to create sub-tasks in infinite async loop to run in parallele till completed in Python

Tags: python-3.x, asynchronous

I would like to gather information every minute, and if it's not empty, then consume the information in a different process. My code right now looks like:

```
from asyncio import gather, create_task, sleep, new_event_loop
import requests
import pandas as pd

client = Client()

async def get_news():
    return requests.get(url)

async def process_news(news):
    await sleep(news.start - pd.Timestamp.utcnow())
    await client.get_information(news)

async def process_all_news(listings):
    tasks = [process_pair(news) for news in listings]

    try:
        await gather(*tasks, return_exceptions=True)
    except Exception as e:
        for task in tasks:
            task.close()

async def main():
    while True:
        listings = await get_news()

        if len(listings) > 0:
            create_task(process_all_news(listings))

        await sleep(60)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    loop = new_event_loop()
    try:
        loop.run_until_complete(main())
    except Exception as e:
        logger.error(e)
    finally:
        loop.stop()
```

Although I have an error

> sys:1: RuntimeWarning: coroutine 'process_news' was never awaited

I want to do it like that, cause the starting date of a news might be several days from now, and I'd like the main to keep running in the meantime.

Any idea please?